# Front camera not working on OnePlus 5T

Tags: 9.0-pie, front-camera, oneplus-5t

Since yesterday my phone's front camera hasn't been working.

- Not working on most apps, including native camera. While touching "switch camera" button in camera application, nothing happens.
- Instagram images from the front camera displays a distorted, stretched image of the rear camera.
- In Dialer keycode(secret code) *#808* for Oneplus devices, "front camera preview" displays rear camera's image. But "camera test" makes the app close(force close) without any error info.
- If I'm not mistaken, during a video call on WhatsApp, the camera froze along with the app, which became unusable until I restarted phone. After that the camera hasn't worked ever since.

What I've tried so far:

- factory reset
- safe mode
- several camera apps
- going back to stable (I was using beta)

Nothing worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: If a factory reset doesn't fix it, it is best you   get it repaired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to fix a possible software problem in any way I could imagine. Nothing worked.

Sent it to OnePlus for repairing and now it is working like new. They had to replace a few components, so it was a hardware problem.